# Cannot import components from react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, button, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React and started exploring bootstrap few days ago. But, whenever I'm trying to import something from react-bootstrap, it's throwing error.

I've already tried reinstalling react-bootstrap. But it doesn't solve the problem. These are my imports:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap/Button'; <-- culprit
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Chart from './components/Chart';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead'; <-- works fine
```

The error is in some line in the ThemeProvider.js, which comes with react-bootstrap.

TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'createContext'

```
  15 | 
  16 | var _react = _interopRequireWildcard(require("react"));
  17 | 
> 18 | var ThemeContext = _react.default.createContext({});
  19 | 
  20 | var Consumer = ThemeContext.Consumer,
  21 |     Provider = ThemeContext.Provider;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import something wrapped around with `{}`, it refers to something that is exported with an explicit name identifier.

In this case: `import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap/Button'` would mean that file has explicitly named one of their exports `Button`. But that's unlikely, because conventionally with these libraries, when you import from a specific file like `/Button`, they will almost always use a default export instead.

The solution would be to simply get the default export by doing:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```

With a default export, you can name the import anything you want, even something like this:

```
import MyButton from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```

Alternatively, you can just import from the head folder. In that case, you would actually have to use `{}` to fetch the named items.

```
import {Button, Input, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: An awesome and simple explanation of named and default exports. A must learn for a person just starting out with React and Node.

Comment: tried everything you mentioned, but no hope. Now it is throwing from line no. 4 of Themeprovider.js. :(

Comment: @Joy are you using create-react-app? It sounds like you don't have your babel configured.

Comment: how to do that ? wait...let me post a screenshot of the error. If that helps you.

Comment: create-react-app is a scaffolding package that essentially sets up your React environment for you. It helps ensure that you can write ES6 JavaScript. Without it, setting up your environment can be a huge headache. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: @Jezpoz thank you! I'm glad you think its helpful :)

Comment: that did it ! I hadn't use create-react-app when I created the project. Rather, I downloaded some project from Internet and kept modifying it. After I created a fresh project, everything is working fine ! Thanks a lot mate :) you guys are awesome !

Comment: @Joy that is awesome! I'm glad it worked for you. Create-react-app is the best :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

or:

```
 import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```

and you need to install bootstrap css and import it:

1.

```
npm install bootstrap
```

2.

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Comment: Error is: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'createContext'
./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/ThemeProvider.js

Comment: @Joy i think this error come from  your react and react-dom version try to upgrade them and try again! use `npm update react react-dom`

Comment: It's solved after I created a new project with create-react-app. Thanks a ton for the help mate !!

Answer (score 0):

When you are importing a Button or any component wrapped around with curly braces, you do not need to include the component name after the backslash.

simply put

import {Button}  from 'react-bootstrap/';

when we import a component without wrapped around with {}, we need to give the component name like this.

import Button  from 'react-bootstrap/Button';